# USB-C to USB-A cable (USB 3.0) with high current at 2m length

Tags: usb, cable, usb-3, smartphone, usb-c

Now I tested multiple cables, but non of them meet these simple requirements:

- USB-C to USB-A connector
- USB 3.0 or USB 3.1 standard
- 2m or 1.8m in length
- high current (> 2 A)
- connector should stay in phone
- data and loading
- shippable

Only Aukey were able to fulfill the criteria (2500 mA, but it stayed not in place). Also the original cable (only 1m), which came with the phone can handle that current.

Now I ordered five other cables, but 1400 mA was the most I got. Is it such a problem to find a USB cable? Are there  any construction problems with USB type C cables over one meter in length?

**Edit:**
I found Sentivus SE-U301-200 USB 3.0 cable (Gen. 1 / 5G / 1.5A) 2.00m, which could deliver 3 A.

It is hard to find out, which USB mode the manifacturer offers.

Comment: What do you mean "should stay in phone" but "it stayed not in place"? What kind of charger (or else) you are trying to get the current from?

Comment: USB Type C, USB 3, and USB 3.1 are all different standards.  Which one do you actually need?

Comment: @AliChen: The connector fall out of the phone if you moved the phone a little bit. Aukey Quick Charge 3.0 34,5 Watt.

Comment: @Ramhound: Type-C is the connector only. The connection itself can be realized with USB 2.0/3.0/3.1. Because USB 3.1/3.0 should be downwards compatible this should not matter? I have all connectors on my PC. It should be faster than 2.0 though.

Comment: Does your phone support the proprietary Qualcomm "Quick Charge" protocol? If yes, what was VBUS voltage when you get 1400mA? How did you measured the 1400mA?

Comment: @AliChen: Yes, the LG G5 supports Quick Charge 3.0. I measured with the app "Ampere". Furthermore, I recheck the values with an electricity meter, which is plugged into the wall.

Comment: @testing - You are not going to find a USB 2.0 cable capable of supporting more then 2A because the USB 2.0 standard.  **USB Type C is not just a connector, its a revision, of the actual USB specification.**  If you use a TYPE-C to USB 2.0 cable, "It should be faster than 2.0 though.", is not possible.

Comment: @Ramhound: *The first thing to realise about USB-C is that it's not a new USB standard in the same way as USB 1.1, USB 2.0, USB 3.0 or the very latest USB 3.1 are. Those upgrades focus on defining what the connection can do in terms of speed and feature improvements, whereas USB-C is all about the physical connection, like with microUSB and miniUSB.* Read more at http://trustedreviews.com/opinions/usb-type-c-everything-you-need-to-know#FfXdkbpM6A0Z2WMs.99

Comment: @testing - The website is wrong you reference is incorrect.  USB Type-C has its own specification, is indeed its own USB standard, separate from USB 3.1

Comment: @Ramhound: Do you have a source? According to this it must be USB 3.0 or 3.1 then. Now I read an article, that Quick Charge, USB 3.0 and USB type C can't work together. Now I'm confused ...

Comment: `Quick Charge` is a term the OEMs coined.  USB 3 supports providing more power to a port.  Its a marketing term for that capability.  USB 3.0 isn't Type-C, my source, is USB.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> high current (> 2 A)

You need to figure out which actual battery-charging mode you're using. There's a large number of them, and it only gets more confusing with Type-C. I've included a couple of tables down the bottom.

---

The first thing to understand is that since you are connecting to a legacy connector/port, none of the new power modes are available. This means you are **not** able to use USB-PD, nor the USB Type-C power modes that can support up to 3 A @ 5 V.

In fact, you are limited to the same legacy modes that would have applied to a Micro-USB connector. As per USB Type-C™ Specification Release 1.2 § 4.5.3.2.4:

> The value of Rp shall indicate an advertisement of Default USB Power (See Table 4-15), even though the cable itself can carry 3 A. This is because the cable has no knowledge of the capabilities of the power source, and any higher current is negotiated via USB BC 1.2 or by proprietary means.

What does this mean, practically? Well, it varies based on the sink device. Some (especially laptops that require USB-PD) will simply refuse to charge. Others (phones) will fall back to proprietary charging methods such as Qualcomm® Quick Charge™, or to USB BC 1.2. These will max out at or under 2 A @ 5 V. Failing that, they'll fall back to the default power levels (e.g. up to 5 units of 100 mA each).

Some cables will (incorrectly!) claim to support Type-C charging modes even though the other end is a legacy connector. This can confuse the sink device into drawing 3 A from a port that does not support it, leading to damage to the charger. These cables are out-of-spec and should never be used.

---

Additionally, many devices will vary current draw based on many conditions. For example, some phones will drastically reduce current draw if the phone is in use (screen is on). Others will only draw full current when the battery is near empty, and slow down as the battery approaches full. These factors must be taken into account when you try to measure current draw.

---

[image: Table 2-1 Summary of power supply options]

<sup>Table 2-1 from USB Type-C™ Specification Release 1.2</sup>

[image: Table 4-14 Precendence of power source usage]

<sup>Table 4-14 from USB Type-C™ Specification Release 1.2</sup>